# Nginx is not proxying requests from React to Flask

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, flask, deployment

I am building a React-Flask app, and am encountering proxying issues when trying to put together my production docker container. My nginx conf is found below:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    #server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        #try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }
    
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


}
```

and my docker compose is:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    image: react-flask-app-api
    environment:
      xxx: "xxx"
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    image: react-flask-app-client
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
  background:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.background
    image: react-flask-app-background
    depends_on:
      - api
      - redis
  redis:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis:7.0.5-alpine 
    expose:
        - 6379
```

My dockerfiles follow pretty much identically what is outlined in [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com) (except using npm instead of yarn).

I have tried all sorts of troubleshooting. All my requests in the frontend use relative routes (i.e. `"/api/getData"`), and I am able to curl `"http://api:5000/..."` from the client container and successfully get results. When I inspect element on the frontend, and click a button that is supposed to hit the api, the network says it's trying to reach: `http://localhost:3000/api/xxx`. Shouldn't this be hitting `http://api:5000/api/xxx` due to how my nginx proxy is set up? Also, when I try to hit the backend with a route that doesn't exist, I get html returned to me that I believe is coming from the frontend which is further confusing me, as it seems like nginx is working? Any guidance at all would be greatly appreciated.